# how to add postscript if condition is met

Tags: postgresql

I have employees, i need to create a new column, which will say, that this employee deserves a reward if he has placed more than 60 orders. How make this?

```
Create VIEW Award_1997 AS
Select employee_id, last_name, first_name, order_date
From orders
Join employees using (employee_id)



Select first_name, last_name, count(employee_id) as orders_count
From Award_1997
Where order_date >= '1997-01-01' and order_date <='1997-12-31'
Group by first_name, last_name
Having count(employee_id) > 60 -- if > 60 4 column = yes otherwise no
```

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend here is the `CASE` statement

```sql
CASE WHEN condition THEN result
     [WHEN ...]
     [ELSE result]
END
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE

```sql
CASE WHEN COUNT(employee_id) > 60 THEN 'YES'
ELSE 'NO' 
END AS "COLUMN_NAME"
```